# Play streamed audio in browser (Asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, audio, wav, response.write

I am trying to get this to work for quite some time now. I have an asp.net page in which I am trying to play a wav file. The code in the page load event is as follows:

```
Response.Clear()  
Response.ContentType = "audio/wav"  
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + "temp.wav")  
Dim filePath As String = Server.MapPath("/temp.wav")  
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath) Then  
    'Here I am converting the file to a byte array,as eventually I'll be creating the wav files on the fly  
    Dim fileBytes As Byte() = GetFileBytes(filePath)  
    Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes)  
    Response.Flush()  
End If
```

The problem I am having is every time I run this page, the windows media player opens up. I would like the audio to be played using some inbuilt plugin in the browser. Something like, when you click on a voice icon, how the sound pops up without opening any player.

If I have the same content in an ashx handler, would it be better?

I could not use the embed tag because, I shall not be having a physical file on the server, it would be generated on the fly using a response stream.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use Flash or ActiveX, or something like that.

Comment: Do you know if I can find a good example of this somewhere as I do not have any experience with Flash / ActiveX